# How do we define a Vector of functions in Java where functions remember their parameters?

Tags: java, function, vector

Suppose I have a list of functions with their arguments: f(a), g(b), h(c)

I now want to create a Vector as follows `Vector<Type> v = new Vector<>()` and do the following: `v.addElement(f(a))` and `v.get(0)` returns f(a). Can this be accomplished ?

Comment: Why is this voted down, it's a perfectly reasonable question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define an interface

```
public interface Command {

    public int myFunction(String param);
}
```

An then implement the interfaces

```
public class ImplementedCommand1 implements Command{

    @Override
    public int myFunction(String param) {
        // Your code calculation
        return 0;
    }

}

public class ImplementedCommand2 implements Command{

    @Override
    public int myFunction(String param) {
        // Your code calculation
        return 0;
    }

}
```

Finally you use your functions

```
    Vector<Command> v = new Vector<>();
    v.addElement(new ImplementedCommand1());
    v.addElement(new ImplementedCommand2());

    Command command1 = v.get(0);

    command1.myFunction("Hello");

    Command command2 = v.get(1);

    command2.myFunction("Hello2");
```

Answer (score 0):

You could have an interface like the following:

```
public interface MyFunction
{
    void doSomething(int a);
}
```

Now say you have two implementations of that interface that do different things when doSomething is called.

```
public class MyCoolFunction implements MyFunction
{
    public void doSomething(int a)
    {
        System.out.println("You passed in " + a);
    }
}

public class MyNotSoCoolFunction implements MyFunction
{
    public void doSomething(int a)
    {
        System.out.println("Hello");
    }
}
```

Then you can have a list of them like this:

```
List<MyFunction> functions = new ArrayList<>();
functions.add(new MyCoolFunction());
functions.add(new MyNotSoCoolFunction());
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
    Vector<Function<Integer, String>> v = new Vector<>();
    v.addElement(a -> "function0 body, arg=" + a);
    v.addElement(a -> "function1 body, arg=" + a);
    System.out.println(v.get(0).apply(7));
    // -> function0 body, arg=7
```